# Which ORM is best for nodejs? (Without Typescript and with typescript)

Tags: node.js

I am nodejs developer. I want to create online shop website with api for mobile applications also (android, ios). But I am not decide which ORM can be used for my requests. I am using postgresql database.

Request:

1. Fast connections, responses (fastest for all)
2. Clean understanding code
3. Secure

I think below ORM are good:

1. express + sequelize
2. loopback
   ......

Which ORM or solution is best for my requests?

Comment: github.com/gradii/fedaco. it port laravel eloquent code to typescript

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Checkout [Typeorm](http://typeorm.io/#/)

TypeORM is an ORM that can run in NodeJS, Browser, Cordova, PhoneGap, Ionic, React Native, NativeScript, Expo, and Electron platforms and can be used with TypeScript and JavaScript (ES5, ES6, ES7, ES8). Its goal is to always support the latest JavaScript features and provide additional features that help you to develop any kind of application that uses databases - from small applications with a few tables to large scale enterprise applications with multiple databases.

TypeORM supports both Active Record and Data Mapper patterns, unlike all other JavaScript ORMs currently in existence, which means you can write high quality, loosely coupled, scalable, maintainable applications the most productive way.

Comment: What are you think about graphql?

Comment: Depends what your application needs are. GraphQL also needs some investigation of your side. Can you offer it to have this in your application to be build?

Comment: Is anyone using TypeORM in a released react native app?  I would love to find an ORM replacement for Realm.  I failed to get https://github.com/typeorm/react-native-example to run on either Android or iOS.  
https://github.com/typeorm/react-native-example/issues/4
https://github.com/typeorm/react-native-example/issues/2

Comment: It is important to note (though) that TypeORM does not currently support polymorphic relations out of the box. There are ways to achieve polymorphic relations with it but most of them are ugly and create some technical debt.

Answer (score 9):

I am using [Typeorm](http://typeorm.io/#/) with Postgresql. I've been trying sequelize too, but finally I decided to use typeorm because the code is clean and maintainable, your code is elegant and easy to read, support multiple DBMs, decoratos, it's a great ORM. I am using it with Typescript and Express.
I hope you can actually consider using it.

Comment: Typeorm is buggy library. For example, The bug "Migration generation drops and creates columns instead of altering resulting in data loss" is opened 4 years ago and 0 fixes were provided. https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3357

Answer (score 8):

I prefer [Sequelize ORM](https://sequelize.org/) as it has a better query syntax in my opinion and when you add something like [sequelizejs-decorators](https://github.com/weagle08/sequelizejs-decorators) you get the nicety of decorators to define your tables with the better query syntax.

Comment: I started with sequelize, but it's making me sad, I'm thinking about switching. Too many inelegant corner cases / semi-undocumented functionality.

Comment: I have run into some undocumented functionality and functionality that is flaky/brittle, but nothing that has made me want to go to another ORM yet. I've tried a couple of the other ORMs (namely TypeORM and another that I do not recall the name of in my early days of NodeJS development) and have come back to sequelize each time because the others have had quirks that bother me more than anything I've found in sequelize.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yes, I have to see if there's anything better, there might not be :-(

Answer (score 5):

A young alternative to typeorm, that I am trying and seems good, is [mikro-orm](https://b4nan.github.io/mikro-orm/).

Answer (score 5):

[ObjectionJS](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/) is a good one in my opinion. It uses [KnexJS](http://knexjs.org/) SQL query builder. Both are compatible with TypeScript. Knex uses migration pattern so you can rollback to your previous state with single command. It's migration system is more like Laravel's famous [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent).

Answer (score 3):

I'd check out [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io) – a type-safe ORM for Node.js and TypeScript.

Since you mentioned "Clean understanding code", it's worth mentioning that Prisma uses the Prisma schema as a declarative source of truth for your database schema and generating the actual database access code. This approach has the advantage of not needing to define model classes, thereby reducing the amount of code you write.

For more information on Prisma's approach to ORMs, [check this article out](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/overview/prisma-in-your-stack/is-prisma-an-orm).

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am the author of this library.

[Kiss-ORM](https://github.com/Seb-C/kiss-orm) is an ORM for NodeJS and Typescript. It uses a data-mapper pattern, and it's core philosophy is to help you enough but at the same time not to "get in the middle".

It allows you to write and concatenate SQL queries in a secure way, because SQL is just fine and very powerful.

Since it does not add much abstraction layers between your code and the database, you can get the same performance and customization capabilities as directly using a package like `node-postgres`.